# Does Fuller's Golden Pride age well?

Tags: aging

Has any of you guys ever aged Fuller's Golden Pride? Does it age well? How was your experience with it?

To be honest I don't remember the beer so that well, and whether it has a good level of melanoidins and residual sugar worth to age. This beer is quite different from other english barley wines, known to age well, so if someone has ever done it, I would appreciate some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: How is it different from other barley wines?

Comment: It's less caramelized compared to other classic english barleywines like J. W. Lees Harvest Ale and Thomas Hardy's Ale. Even if you compare them in color, Golden Pride is much more golden than ruby or dark. Well, what does that matter? The thing is that one of the key components for a beer to age well are melanoidins, created in large amounts in caramelization process. So, that is one of the main characteristics we look for in a beer when considering to age it, and Fuller's Golden Pride doesn't have it so that much. But, it doesn't necessarily mean it will not age well. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself. I didn't remember the beer very well as of the time I posted the question, and now I've had it again.

I turns out this beer is actually an english barleywine, even mentioned by BJCP style-guide as an example of the style. And, as so, it's (very) well-suited for aging, considering its high ABV, melanoidins and beta acids levels (english hops are high in beta acids, which age well, in opposition to popular most popular american hops).

I'll get some bottles for my cellar.

Answer (score 2):

I have not aged one yet (they only arrived in my country a month ago!), but I am sure it should age well.

Due to the higher ABV it should develop some fruity aromas and flavours, maybe even go into the sherry-like arena.

If you do age them, age them properly (cold/cool and in the dark) and try one every year. Certain beers age amazingly well in the beginning, but then go sideways after year 5, others you can leave for ages!

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

The above picture is actually from my aged beer that I cracked open tonight. I purchased this particular beer from Lakenheath, England in September 2014. The beer is very much well-aged and has hints of sherry within. It has little carbonation, as do most English Ales.